# I encounter an error when run a flutter app . AssetManifest imported from two libraries

Tags: flutter, google-font-api, google-fonts

I have bought a source code from codecanyon, but getting this error, also tried to reach there support, they didn't replying me.
the errors

/C:/src/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:14:1: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
import 'asset_manifest.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:32:31: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
AssetManifest assetManifest = AssetManifest();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sliver_tools-0.2.10/lib/src/sliver_stack.dart:282:55: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.

- 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
  final AbstractNode? targetParent = renderObject.parent;
  ^
  /C:/src/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sliver_tools-0.2.10/lib/src/sliver_stack.dart:283:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
  if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to upgrade google_fonts, but still getting error.
Here is my pubspace.yml

name: shop_o
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+3

environment:
sdk: ">=2.18.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

auth_buttons: ^3.0.0
badges: ^3.0.2
stream_transform: ^2.0.0

## chat message ui design

cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
chat_bubbles: ^1.2.0
carousel_slider: ^4.0.0

## network connectivity checker

connectivity_plus: ^3.0.3
country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
custom_pop_up_menu: ^1.2.3+1

## functional programming thingies

dartz: ^0.10.1
dots_indicator: ^2.1.0

## value equality

equatable: ^2.0.3

## for state management

flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3

flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
flutter_svg: ^1.1.0

## service locator

#get_it: ^7.2.0
google_fonts: ^3.0.1
grouped_list: ^5.1.2

## remote api call

http: ^0.13.4

## image picker from device

image_picker: ^0.8.5
intl: ^0.17.0
pinput: ^2.2.31

## local storage

shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
sliver_tools: ^0.2.5

## datetime to time ago

timeago: ^3.2.2
toggle_switch: ^2.0.1
webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3

## payment

flutter_stripe: ^3.2.0
flutter_font_awesome_web_names:
git:
url: https://github.com/Mythar/flutter_font_awesome_web_names
ref: master
flutter_credit_card: ^3.0.1
shimmer: ^2.0.0
flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.3.0
rename: ^2.0.1

## The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
dio: ^5.0.3
dash_chat_2: ^0.0.15
laravel_echo:
git:
url: https://github.com/kakajansh/echo.git
ref: master
pusher_client:
git:
url: https://github.com/DumbDev168/pusher_client.git
ref: master
onesignal_flutter: ^3.4.1

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

mocktail: ^0.3.0
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0

flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

uses-material-design: true

assets:
- assets/
- assets/images/
- assets/icons/
- assets/stripe/

flutter_icons:
android: "launcher_icon"
ios: true
image_path: "assets/launcher_icon.png"